# Some codes in a thread are not repeated

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

```
package TheWork;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;  

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable
{
private Cannon P1 = Cannon.getPlayer();
private TheirBullet[] bullets = {};
private TheirRocket[] rockets = {};
private Enemy[] enemies = {};
private long timeCount = 0;
private int timeDis = 10;

public void drawCannon(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect((int)P1.getX() - 20, (int)Cannon.POS_Y, 40, 20);
    g.fillRect((int)P1.getX() - 5, (int)Cannon.POS_Y - 5, 2, 20);
    g.fillRect((int)P1.getX() + 3, (int)Cannon.POS_Y - 5, 2, 20);
}

public void drawGoodBullet(Graphics g)
{
    for(YourBullet temp : P1.bullets)
    {
    if(temp != null && temp.hit == false)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawRect((int)temp.x - 2, (int)temp.y - 2, 4, 4);
        }
    if(temp.hit == true)
        {
            P1.bullets.remove(temp);
        }
    }
}

public void drawBadBullet(Graphics g)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < bullets.length;i++)
    {
        TheirBullet temp = bullets[i];
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawRect((int)temp.x - 2, (int)temp.y - 2, 4, 4);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < rockets.length;i++)
    {
        TheirRocket temp = rockets[i];
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect((int)temp.x - 1, (int)temp.y - 4, 2, 8);
    }

}

public void drawEnemy(Graphics g)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < enemies.length;i++)
    {
        Enemy temp = enemies[i];
        if(temp instanceof Fodder)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else
        {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
        g.fillRect((int)temp.getX() - 10, (int)temp.getY() - 5, 20, 10);
        g.fillRect((int)temp.getX()-2, (int)temp.getY(), 4, 10);
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    drawCannon(g);
    drawGoodBullet(g);
    drawBadBullet(g);
    drawEnemy(g);   
}


@Override
public void run() 
{   
    timeCount++;
    System.out.println("check 1");
    if(timeCount % 300 == 0)
    {
        Enemy poorThing = generate();
        System.out.println("get");
        enemies = Arrays.copyOf(enemies, enemies.length + 1);
        enemies[enemies.length - 1] = poorThing;
    }
    System.out.println("check 2");
    for(int i = 0;i < enemies.length;i++)
    {
        Enemy temp = enemies[i];
        temp.move();
    }
    System.out.println("check 3");
    while(true) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(timeDis);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.out.println("check 4");
    this.repaint();
    System.out.println("check 5");
    }

} 




@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && P1.getX() > 20)
    {
        P1.goLeft();
        P1.setWay(-1);
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && P1.getX() < 780) 
    {
        P1.goRight();
        P1.setWay(1);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        if(P1.bullets.size() <= 6)
        {
            P1.shoot();
        }
    }
    this.repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static Enemy generate() 
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Random s = new Random();
    Random t = new Random();
    int chance = r.nextInt(10);
    int dirDec = s.nextInt(2);
    int tirDec = t.nextInt(5);
    if(chance >= 8)
    {
        System.out.println("A acquired");
        return new Danger(dirDec, tirDec);

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("B acquired");
        return new Fodder(dirDec, tirDec);

    }

}


}
```

What's happening is: I'm trying to create a game where a player object(of Cannon class) shoots enemy objects (of Fodder and Danger classes, both are subclasses of Enemy class) which are generated by the generate() method, which is called in the run() method(the thread is started in another class).

However, I never get a single enemy object created. I inserted some println sentences to check how the program flows, the result is that:"A acquired" and "B acquired" never happen, and all I get are "Check 1","Check 2","Check 3", then an endless loop of "Check 4" and "Check 5".

Also, the player object does get created and properly painted, but only randomly. In different attempts to run the codes without changing anything, the results always change between working and nothing-painted.

I really want to know where I did wrong, thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider posting [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the while(true) does not include the enemy generation. the condition can be entered only once, since timecount at that time (the first call of run) is 1 and not 0, that means never.

Comment: Wow, as I put everything under while(true), it did work, thanks so much! I guess I had a wrong idea about run() before, thought it always auto repeat. Although, do you have any idea about why the program only run properly sometimes? Like all I do is press "Run" button and the result is never stable.

Comment: @OryolUperi Sounds like you've got concurrency problems. Multithreaded programming isn't easy, and if you haven't studied the tutorials carefully, your code is probably filled with race conditions and other bugs.